# Check element style and add class

Tags: jquery, magento, if-statement, element, addclass

Why is this not working? I'm trying to add a clas so I can add padding to the default Magento CMS image styles - big thanks in advance. Ignore the j - it has to be there

```
if ($j('.cms-page-view .std img').css('float') == 'left') {
            $j('.cms-page-view .std img').addClass('img-left');
        } 
        else if ($j('.cms-page-view .std img').css('float') == 'right') {
            $j('.cms-page-view .std img').addClass('img-right');
        }
        else {
            $j('.cms-page-view .std img').addClass('img-normal');
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) add the classes in each elements context

```
$j('.cms-page-view .std img').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this); //Here this refers to element in an iteration
    if (elem.css('float') == 'left') {
        elem.addClass('img-left');
    } 
    else if (elem.css('float') == 'right') {
        elem.addClass('img-right');
    }
    else {
        elem.addClass('img-normal');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As Satpal said you should use for each loop to iterate through each element because class selector will return list of elements

```
$j('.cms-page-view .std img').forEach(function(item){

  if ($j(item).css('float') == 'left') {
        $j(item).addClass('img-left');
    } 
    else if (item).css('float') == 'right') {
        $j(item).addClass('img-right');
    }
    else {
        $j(item).addClass('img-normal');
    }
}
);
```